# Resume Application from a Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a notification when user opens an activity, if user put app in background and touch up in notification, app tries to re-open activity, but in fact a new activity is opened and last data is lost.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making the Activity as a single task by adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Then you need to handle the new data via `onNewIntent()`, something like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    ...
    processExtraData();
  }

  @Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    processExtraData();
  }

  protected void processExtraData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    ...
    // process the extra here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for me this worked;

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Single task like suggested in the approved answer does work as well, but it's not recommended;

"singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications."